# MySql replication of selective table

Tags: mysql, replication

Consider there is one DB -DB1 on one machine-M1,  which has many tables. 
There is a different DB2 on other machine-B .

Now there is a requirement where I need to replicate **just one table** from DB1 to machine B ,
so that a union query can be fired involving 1 table from  both DB1 and 1 table from DB2.

Requirement is to replicate only one table selectively from DB1 to machine2.

Please assist in this ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can grant replication on a single table.

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON database.TABLE1 TO 'repl'@'%.mydomain.com';
```

Comment: Above command didnt work ,it gave me error 
I replaced db,table,user and ip acc to my needs.

ERROR 1144 (42000): Illegal GRANT/REVOKE command; please consult the manual to see which privileges can be used

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate a single table using [replicate-wild-do-table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-wild-do-table) along with selective database and binlogging options, but it's really not a nice way to go and is probably saving up trouble.

One flaw in your plan is that while you can do a union query across multiple databases, you can't do them across multiple connections, which is what you'd have. Why do you need to split the query like this anyway?

Answer (score 0):

add replicate-do-table in my.cnf

```
replicate-do-table=dbname.tablename
```

reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db